# C# SharePoint Exception 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException' when GetFileByServerRelativeURL

Tags: c#, sharepoint, listitem

I am getting a `PropertyException` on the 2nd part of this code. The 1st part uploads the file as expected. After the `context.ExecuteQuery();` I am then getting:

> 'uploadedFile.CheckInComment' threw an exception of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException'

I am not sure why as the context should be OKsince it did upload the file.

I am going to try to update some meta data fields on the document I just uploaded.

```
    Folder currentRunFolder = site.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(barRootFolderRelativeUrl + "/");
FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation
{
    Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@p),
    Url = Path.GetFileName(@p),
    Overwrite = true
};

currentRunFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
currentRunFolder.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
newUrl = siteUrl + barRootFolderRelativeUrl + "/" + Path.GetFileName(@p);

// Set document properties
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadedFile = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(newUrl);
ListItem listItem = uploadedFile.ListItemAllFields;
listItem["TestEQCode"] = "387074";
listItem.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: what is uploadedFile  variable here?
this error usually occurs when you try to access a field which you havent requested from sharepoint..

Comment: I actually get this error on the uploadedFile variable.  The new Url is correct as I can take that item and open up IE and paste it in and the file then opens up.  But I am getting the error on the GetFileByServicerRelativeUrl.

Comment: try to put context.ExecuteQuery(); before listItem["TestEQCode"] = "387074";

Comment: I am getting the error on the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadedFile = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this.

```
currentRunFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
//currentRunFolder.Update();
context.Load(newFile);
context.ExecuteQuery();
//newUrl = siteUrl + barRootFolderRelativeUrl + "/" + Path.GetFileName(@p);

// Set document properties
//Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadedFile = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(newUrl);
ListItem listItem = newFile.ListItemAllFields;
listItem["TestEQCode"] = "387074";
listItem.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: I get a syntax error on the ctx.Load(newFile).  I then changed it to context.Load(newFile), but this too is getting a Parameter error.  This is a winform, utilizing the SharePoint.Client dll.

Comment: Should be context.Load(newFile);  What's the parameter error?

Comment: Ok so eventhough the ListItems is NULL I can set the TestEQCode and update and the field is getting updated on the SharePoint side.  This whole time I was concerned on the ListItems getting the actual meta data list, but really it doesn't need that.  I just will have to Hard Code those items and it will update.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so eventhough the ListItems is NULL I can set the TestEQCode and update and the field is getting updated on the SharePoint side. This whole time I was concerned on the ListItems getting the actual meta data list, but really it doesn't need that. I just will have to Hard Code those items and it will update. –